# TcServer create a cluster-node template based on tomcat-8

Tags: tomcat8, tcserver

I am using TcServer Release 3.1.0 on a Windows Environment, specifically the "cluster-node" template, the problem consist that when I run the command to create the server it's based on tomcat-7, and I need it to be based on tomcat-8, here is the command that I am using it:

```
tcruntime-instance.bat create myserver1 --template cluster-node
```

and here is the message that i get from the command prompt:

```
Applying template 'base-tomcat-7'
```

Reading on the documentation it says that depends on the tc Runtime version to select between "base-tomcat-7" or "base-tomcat-8" to be used by the instance, so any ideas to make mandatory apply the base-tomcat-8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tc Server version defaults to tc Runtime 7. You need to pass in the --version parameter specifying the 8.0.XX version along with the templates you want.